# Maven not found in Jenkins

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, jenkins

I am running my Maven/Spring project in Jenkins (just testing it out, first time) using the shell script option with:

`mvn spring-boot:run`

I get the build error:
`/Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/jenkins8087926087546049217.sh: line 2: mvn: command not found`

How can I fix this? Its a Spring-boot app. It works fine when I run `mvn spring-boot:run` via command line.

Comment: What is the output of `which mvn` in a Terminal.app session?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, Navigate to Manage Jenkins and click on Global Tool Configuration, In Maven section click on the 'Add Maven' button and provide the maven installation path
in MAVEN_HOME and save configurations.

[image: Maven config in Jenkins]

Comment: There is no "Maven section," can you provide some direction?

Comment: @Charo, take a look at the snapshot I have shared in my answer for the reference.

Comment: wow, I don't even have this in my Jenkins config system... Any idea?

Comment: Refer these, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/jenkins_maven_setup.htm or http://www.itcuties.com/tools/jenkins-installation-and-configuration-with-maven-ant-and-github/  see if it helps

Comment: Click on "Global Tool Configuration". The link is http://your-jenkins-host/configureTools/

Answer (score 10):

"Manage Jenkins"->"Global Tool Configuration"
[image]

if still not work, add the following to "Execute shell"

```
export MAVEN_HOME=/opt/maven
export PATH=$PATH:$MAVEN_HOME/bin
mvn --version
mvn clean package
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem on windows. Maven worked fine from console, but failed when called as cmd command from Jenkins.

The reason is that Jenkins is installed and run as a ‚system user‘ service. This means the process can‘t see the ENV variables and PATH of your user (user level). Setting up maven in PATH and ENV variables on system level makes the trick.

P.S.: @Charo the maven config moved from Configure System to Global Tool Configuratin in newer Jenkins versions

Comment: Example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45923316/mvn-not-found-in-jenkins-slave?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

```
export MAVEN_HOME=/opt/maven
export PATH=$PATH:$MAVEN_HOME/bin
mvn --version
mvn clean package
```

and then mvn install

Answer (score 2):

I also met the problem and solved it. I think you may be using a "FreeStyle Project" instead of a "Maven Project" when you creating a new project via "New Item" button.

In FreeStyle Project, Jenkins may not read environment variables in Linux server and the Maven installations in "Global Tool Configuration", so I configured environment variables repeatedly in "Configure System". Then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

makesure you maven config is true.
you can use **cmd** and run:

```
mvn -version
```

if no error, try

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is an stupid answer but I forgot to put maven as tool in the Jenkinsfile.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        maven 'Maven 3.8.6'
        jdk 'Java 17.0.4.1'
    }
    stages {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the similar issue where I have put the Name As maven-3.3.9

And Placed the MAVEN_HOME LIKE :  E:\Softwares\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue in my ubuntu 16.04 machine and the actual reason is the maven bin directory path is not set $PATH variable.

How to check?

1. you can append below lines in execute shell prompt of Jenkins GUI.

   ```
   echo $M2_HOME
   echo $PATH
   mvn clean install
   ```

   When you will build again then you will see M2_HOME or maven bin path is not set in $PATH variable.
2. Or you can log in in to Jenkins user from the root and run following commands.

   ```
   su - Jenkins
   echo $PATH
   ```

Solution::

```
 1. logged in to root user.
 2. then this command cd /etc/profile.d/
 3. vim maven.sh then add below lines
    export M2_HOME=/usr/local/maven
    export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
 4. run this command chmod +x maven.sh
 5. then login to jenkins user (su - jenkins) then see again maven path is set or not via (echo $PATH) command.
 6. If the path is set then restart Jenkins service 
    service jenkins restart
    and re-login in Jenkin GUI (http://localhost:8080/)
 7. Now rebuild your job then you will get success :-)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the mvn not found error if your agent is a docker image without maven in it

Answer (score 0):

1. set Java JDK in jenkins manage
2. set Maven in jenkins maange

in Command execute set

```
set path=C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.7\bin
```

your path from environment in windows

`cd C:\Users\X\IdeaProjects\ "nameofprocject"`

just copy from Intellij/Eclipse

`mvn -Dtest=MainPageTests test`  -> goal from Maven  to run