# "mvn: not found" in Jenkins slave

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have Jenkins slave with Java and Maven installed (environment is Debian). I can run "java -version" and "mvn -version" commands in console.

But when I try to execute shell commands in Jenkins job, then I get "mvn: not found" error. Java command works fine.

[image: jenkins shell]

Can you tell me what should I do to be able to run shell "mvn" command on slave?

Comment: You need to configure the location of such tools in the global tools location configuration in Jenkins and define the particular path on the node configuration...

Comment: @khmarbaise and I have to do this everytime when I add new tool in one of my slaves? I mean tool which is not on the list of the global tools

Answer (score 12, accepted):

run *mvn --version* locally to get Mavan home path

```
[sa@jmeter03.test3]# mvn --version

Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T08:41:47-08:00)mvn --version
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.8.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_131/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

then add the following to **Execute shell** prior to running any mvn command. That'll do it.

```
export M2_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.3.9 # your Mavan home path
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
mvn --version
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me on CentOS 7 and Freestyle Project on Jenkins

Comment: Thank you Serhii Aksiutin ,  you are a life saver. I was trying to create a fre style project in docker and your anwer helped.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution:
You just have to set proper **Environment variable** in node configuration like in the picture below.
[image]