# Jenkins mvn: command not found Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, terminal, java-home

I set up Jenkins with two Execute shell builds Java -version and mvn -version. Console output shows the below error.
[image: Console output]

My Global tool config is:
[image: Global tool config]

Terminal output for Java -version and mvn version, Java_Home and Maven_Home is:
[image: Terminal]

This is my .bash_profile:
[image: .bash_profile]

So Java and Maven is installed correctly. Java home and Maven home commands returns null but Jenkins build passed for Java -version, fails only for mvn -version. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: iirc jenkins doesn't run as a your user, so the content of *your* `.bash_profile` should be irrelevant.

Comment: Do you run Jenkins inside of docker?

Comment: @ – kio21, No. I don't have Docker. I am running the build from Jenkins website.

Comment: Found the fix at- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45923316/mvn-not-found-in-jenkins-slave?rq=1 Serhii Aksiutin's answer worked for me.