# Jenkins can't find Maven after updating to Java 17

Tags: java, linux, maven, jenkins

I have a Raspberry Pi that I'm running Jenkins on to compile and deploy Java applications. We have migrated to Spring 3 so now it requires Java 17 to run. For some reason, it's not possible to install Java 17 using apt-get, so I uninstalled all of the previous Java versions and installed it directly from the tar file as it's documented resulting in:

```bash
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ echo $JAVA_HOME
/opt/jdk/jdk-17.0.1+12

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ java -version
openjdk version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.1+12 (build 17.0.1+12)
OpenJDK Server VM Temurin-17.0.1+12 (build 17.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I have proceeded the same way for maven:

```bash
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ echo $MAVEN_HOME
/opt/maven

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ echo $M2_HOME
/opt/apache-maven-3.9.4

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.9.4 (dfbb324ad4a7c8fb0bf182e6d91b0ae20e3d2dd9)
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 17.0.1, vendor: Eclipse Adoptium, runtime: /opt/jdk/jdk-17.0.1+12
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.10.103-v7l+", arch: "arm", family: "unix"
```

So I believe both are properly installed for user **pi**, but not installing it in an *official* way doesn't set up everything automatically.

I have set up a Jenkins job to print all of these for debugging purposes:

```bash
echo $JAVA_HOME
echo $M2_HOME
echo $MAVEN_HOME
java -version
javac -version
mvn -v
```

which prints to console the following:

```bash
Started by user Master Gui
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/echo
[echo] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins3152995503405589329.sh
+ echo /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
+ echo

+ echo

+ java -version
openjdk version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.1+12 (build 17.0.1+12)
OpenJDK Server VM Temurin-17.0.1+12 (build 17.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing)
+ javac -version
javac 17.0.1
+ mvn -v
/tmp/jenkins3152995503405589329.sh: 7: /tmp/jenkins3152995503405589329.sh: mvn: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Java seems to be working, Maven doesn't, and all of the env variables are wrong. Does anybody know what I'm missing here?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try config tools or export path as explained in some answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45777031/maven-not-found-in-jenkins

Comment: I couldn't make it work using any of these. I think the problem is that Jenkins is not loading ~/.bashrc which contains the correct values for everything. I get it doesn't load it cause it's not an interactive shell, but I'm not sure how to make something similar :D

Comment: If I run `alias mvn=/opt/apache-maven-3.9.4/bin/mvn` on top of my Jenkins script, it does work, but I don't think this is an ideal solution

Answer (score 1):

The best course of action is to consistently define both the JDK and maven in the "tools" section of your Jenkinsfile and define both tools in your Jenkins configuration to have Jenkins automatically download the necessary commands.

I have a golden rule that you should never explicitly install build packages on the Jenkins Master/Workers in order to be able to transition to other platforms in the future (I'm not suggesting this is good or best industry practice).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up setting the PATH as a Jenkins environment variable from the settings with the same value as *outside* of Jenkins. I'm not sure this is a proper way to do it or an industry standard but it was the only way I could make it work.